# Why browser locks during ajax call?

Tags: php, ajax, apache, browser

[=== Please see section two, as I rephrased my original question ==== ]
I have a form that calls Ajax on submit. Ajax calls a php code which retrieve data from Mysql.
Everything working without error.

The problem is, while Ajax is stilling waiting to complete the request, I am not able to cancel it. Browser back button does not work. Click in on any other link on page does not work.

It looks like some sort of session lock that locks the browser.

Does this could be any thing with session_write_close()?

```
 function getHistory(){
        startDate = $('#start_date').val();
        endDate = $('#end_date').val();


        $.ajax({
            url: "/coms/reports/jsonHistory",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                startDate: startDate,
                endDate: endDate,
            },
            datatype: "text",
            success: function (responseObj) {
                var resultDataTable = $('#HistoryDataTable').DataTable();
                resultDataTable.clear().draw();
                for (var key in responseObj) {
                    if (responseObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        duration = responseObj[key]['duration'];
                        connection_ip = responseObj[key]['connection_ip'];
                        resultDataTable.row.add([
                            duration,
                            connection_ip
                        ]).draw();
                    }
                }
            },
            complete: function () {
                console.log('here i am');
            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });
}


$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#myFormSubmit").click(function () {
        getHistory();
    });


}
```

I have included the Ajax Block. 
The jsonHistory, is a php code jsonHistory.php that query the database and return JSON. If this code can get about a minute to complete due to large database. So user may change mind and wanted to leave the page, but browser is get locked by Ajax. Also all this is implemented under Zend Framework.

=================================================

## === **Section two: the question is rephrased** ======

I would like to rephrase my question to following:

Situation 1: Old Application on Old Server:

1. open mysite.com/page1.php
2. Select Date range of last 3 month and submit.
3. PHP and Mysql takes 10 minutes to return the result
4. While I am waiting for page1.php to complete its job, I open a new browser tab, and open  mysite.com/page2.php
5. page2.php loads immediately
   [page2.php is just simple Hello World html page]

Situation 2: New Application on New Server"

1. open myothersite.com/page1.php
2. Select Date range of last 3 month and submit.
3. PHP and Mysql takes 10 minutes to return the result
4. While I am waiting for page1.php to complete its job, I open a new browser tab, and open myothersite.com/page2.php
5. page2.php does NOT load. It loads only after page1.php completed its job.  [page2.php is just simple Hello World html page]

So, my question is , what could be the reason for this.
Is it because of differences on Apache setting? Does this do any thing to do with KeepAlive and persistence setting?

KeepAlive is OFF on Apache in old server.
KeepAlive is not defined on New Server.

Is there any other Apache setting or PHP setting that can cause this behavior?

Comment: Can you show us the code snippet ?

Comment: I just added the code and more comment above

Comment: You should add a loading overlay over your user interface so the user knows that the ajax operation is still in progress

Comment: my guess is it has returned and the for loop inside is locking up the page.